# Biblatex-chicago endnotes instead of footnotes with autocite

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, endnotes

I have been using the biblatex-chicago package in my essay to generate footnotes for citations using \autocite and \autocites... but now I wish to have endnotes rather than footnotes. I first load the biblatex-chicago package as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,notes,natbib,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I have tried a variety of creative methods to then use endnotes, including:

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
%begin page
%content here, include references like \autocite[191]{LetHistoryJudge}
%end of content
\theendnotes
```

This successfully includes "Notes" at the end, but it doesn't translate the bib reference into the actual citations. I get "LaTeX Warning: Citation 'LetHistoryJudge' on page 7 undefined on input line 29." and similar warnings for all of my citations. These citations, I might add, work perfectly fine as footnotes when I remove the endnotes package and don't redefine the endnote command as the footnote command. What's the proper way to do this? I haven't found an option in the biblatex-chicago package itself that would allow me to set endnotes instead of footnotes.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: instead of `\let\footnote=\endnote` I'd use `biblatex`'s `notetype=endonly` option. This doesn't get rid of the warnings, though, although the output looks right...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Also, do yourself a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1607754" :)

Comment: loading `endnotes` *after* `biblatex-chicago` works for me

Comment: @henrique really? I get `LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.` either way

Comment: The `biblatex-chicago` package doesn't appear to be obeying `notetype=endonly`. It silently fails to fix the problem, and just leaves undefined citations. Also, I already have the `endnotes` package loaded after the `biblatex-chicago` package.

Comment: @kharms »The `biblatex-chicago` package doesn't appear to be obeying `notetype=endonly`.« -- I don't understand what you're trying to say: I get citations as endnotes just as expected with the option, despite and additional to said warning about undefined references.

Comment: @kharms I didn't suggest this option to get rid of the warnings but to still being able to use regular footnotes.

Comment: @cgnieder, sorry, you're absolutely right... :S

Comment: I think the various `cite` commands from `biblatex` are too clever and something is getting lost in the writing to the `.ent` file; this is easy to check if you redefine `\autocite` this way: `\renewcommand{\autocite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}` and look at the new `.ent` file. One simple solution would be to `\nocite` everything you actually cite; unfortunately, it is tricky to prepend a `\nocite{<key>}` to every `\smartcite{<key>}` through simple redefinitions because of the way the `\DeclareCiteCommand`s work (unless you never use any optional arguments in your `\autocite` commands).

Answer (score 3):

I know this type of problem, and have identified a few issues myself:

- Make sure you have installed all the packages of biblatex-chicago as per the documentation
- Update your package repository to the latest
- Make sure you refresh your FNDB and Update Formats (from settings menu in MiKteX)
- I used winedit 8, and biber, so I needed to get an extra plugin called lateXify, which compiles, does the cross referencing, compiles again, etc...

Winedit is not free, but the trial version is pretty functional and it's not expensive.

I needed to install latex on another computer, and had to go through all the pain again, and realised, following the steps above, correctly, got me where I wanted.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

@jon's comment helped. It's important to remember the \theendnotes command at the end of your document.

```
\usepackage[notes,notetype=endonly,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes,setspace}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\let\cite=\autocite
\renewcommand{\autocite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Hello.\cite{tom1999}
\clearpage
\theendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```