# Endnotes instead of footnotes and parencite with page numbers

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes, endnotes

I am looking to transfer `\parencite`s and `\footnote`s to endnotes. Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126262/biblatex-chicago-endnotes-instead-of-footnotes-with-autocite) thread, I half succeeded. It works beautifully for every instance, except for one where there is a page argument (Example 5).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\ref.bib}
@article{A,
   author = {Doe, Jane and Doe, John},
   title = {Title},
   journal = {Journal of Something},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-29},
   year = {1997},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{B,
   author = {Doe, Janelle and Doe, Jack},
   title = {Title},
   journal = {Journal of Something},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-29},
   year = {2000},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{C,
   author = {Doe, Jasmin and Doe, Jared},
   title = {Title},
   journal = {Journal of Something},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-29},
   year = {2001},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{D,
   author = {Doe, Janelle and Doe, Jack},
   title = {Title},
   journal = {Journal of Something},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-29},
   year = {2002},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
@article{E,
   author = {Doe, Janelle and Doe, Jack},
   title = {Title},
   journal = {Journal of Something},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-29},
   year = {2004},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\let\footnote=\endnote
\renewcommand{\parencite}[1]{\footnote{\cite{#1}}}


\begin{document}

Example\footnote{Text.}.    
Example\parencite{A}.
Example\parencite{A,B,C,D,E}. 
Example\footnote{\cite[31--32]{A} More text after cite.}. 
Example\parencite[337]{A}. 

\theendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include an optional argument in `\renewcommand` so that it can deal with the `prenote`.

```
\renewcommand{\parencite}[2][]{\footnote{\cite[#1]{#2}.}}
```

Depending on your usage, this is perhaps less than ideal. It won't deal with `postnote`s, also not with `parencites` etc. The conversion of `parencite` to `footnote`/`endnote` will also require local intervention because of position relative to punctuation (usually `parencite` will follow a space and be followed by a period, while `footcite` will follow a period and be followed by a space). But I'm following your initial approach to the issue here.

The result is:

[image]